# problem with collision of UIImageViews

Tags: iphone, arrays, xcode, uiimageview, collision-detection

```
-(void)moveTheImage{
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [views count]; i++) {
    image = [views objectAtIndex:i];
    X = [[XArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    Y = [[YArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
image.center=CGPointMake(image.center.x + X, image.center.y + Y);


    if(!intersectFlag)
    {    

        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(image.frame,centre.frame))    
        {
            intersectFlag = YES;    
            label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];

            ++count;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        if(!CGRectIntersectsRect(image.frame,centre.frame))
        {
            intersectFlag = NO;
        }
    }


}
```

I would like that every time  "image" intersect with "centre" the count increase of 1 but when there is a collision the count grows very fast until "image" doesn't touch "centre". More precisely "image" moves an then pass through "centre" and the count grows and when "image" is not in contact with "centre" the counter stops.How cn I solve this please? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: There's a lack of details here. First: how (and how often) is called `moveTheImage`? And also, where is `count` declared and initialized? Without this, I personally can't help you much...

Comment: there is a CADisplayLink on moveTheImage and count is declared in my viewDidLoad but the problem come from my array views I thing

Comment: The behavior your describe seems correct to me, as you call `moveTheImage` for each drawn frame, lets say, at 30fps, if the moving image takes 3 seconds to move through `centre` then it will be counted 90 times... You should use a `NSMutableSet` and stock in it the objects in collision, and remove those who are not. Or you can add an attribute to your objects representing the collision state, and count them.

Comment: sorry but can you explain more or with a sample code one of your solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

As I said on the last comment, I think your count problem comes because of the frame rate.

So you can use an `NSMutableSet` which will contain all the objects being in collision.

In the interface, you declare your new set:

```
NSMutableSet * collisionObjects;
```

In the init method:

```
collisionObjects = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
```

In the dealloc:

```
[collisionObjects release];
```

And your method becomes:

```
-(void)moveTheImage{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [views count]; i++) {
        image = [views objectAtIndex:i];
        X = [[XArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
        Y = [[YArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
        image.center=CGPointMake(image.center.x + X, image.center.y + Y);

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(image.frame,centre.frame)) {
           // If the object is in collision, we add it to our set
           // If it was already in it, it does nothing
           [collisionObjects addObject:image];
        }
        else {
           // If the object is not in collision we remove it, 
           // just in case it was in collision last time.
           // If it was not, it does nothing.
           [collisionObjects removeObject:image];
        }
    }

    // The intersectFlag is updated : YES if the set is empty, NO otherwise.
    intersectFlag = [collisionObjects count] > 0;
    // We display the count of objects in collision
    label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [collisionObjects count]];
}
```

And this way you always have the count of your objects in collision using `[collisionObjects count]`.